# Oracle datatypes list

Tags: database, oracle, types

Does anyone know of a good link that has a listing of the Oracle specific datatypes for a beginner?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Staying in the realm of the bloomin' obvious, the Oracle documentation set is always the first - and best - place to start.  [Check it out.](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#i45441)

**Edit**

The SS64 site is clear but very out-of-date.  Its latest syntax is the 9i set, two major releases off the pace.  It is also not complete.  For instance, the SELECT page doesn't mention the WITH clause, which was a very useful feature introduced in 9i.

If you want a redaction of the more recent documentation then Dan Morgan's Library site is exhaustive (and occasionally exhausting).  Here is his page on [Oracle datatypes](http://www.morganslibrary.com/reference/datatypes.html).

Comment: +1 for pointing to the Oracle docs (obviously the last word) - but the SS64 site gives you a lot of information very quickly, and is a good heads-up for a beginner. As far as being out-of-date is concerned, that sometimes happens with manufacturers' info too :-(